# I've somehow got rid of my navigation bar so that it no longer appears in layout mode, which is a pain

Tags: properties, navigation

I've had this happen a few times, and I can't work out what I've pressed. Now any time I want to use the navigation bar I have to switch over to a different workspace (I think I mean navigation bar: it might also be called the "properties bar"? It's where you go to do stuff like turn down the intensity of your light).
Does anyone have an idea what I might've done?
Thanks in advance, I'm really new to Blender and I couldn't find anyone having the same problem.[image: Missing in Layout Mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the little arrow icon to show the *Navigation Bar* for the *Properties*. You've likely dragged the properties area (edge marked in blue) when you wanted to resize the entire area. Instead you should drag with the cursor placed at the green line for the intended result.

[image: Hidden navigation bar]

[image: Resize area]

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed this; I kept losing that darn menu and I was totally bemused.

Comment: I think I assumed the arrow was just for resizing the whole modifiers panel or smth. I cannot tell you how frustrating this was, again, thx so much!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Oh, cool, will do

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the little arrow next to Add Modifier?

It looks like you accidentally held and dragged it closed which is an option.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy